# Does thread's getId() give guaranteed sequence?

Tags: java, multithreading

Does thread's getId() give guaranteed sequence? Please share any reference if it stats the same.

Comment: Have you read the documentation and does it answer your question?

Comment: Guaranteed by what?  By specification?  By implementation?

Answer (score 2):

The javadoc doesn't guarantee any particular sequence for thread ID values.

The only thing that is guaranteed<sup>1</sup> is this:

> The thread ID is unique and remains unchanged during its lifetime.

You could also look at the source code of the `Thread` class and/or the native code implementation to see what they do.  For Java 6 through Java 15, the ID is initialized from a sequence number that is incremented each time a new thread is created.  The behavior is unlikely to change, but this cannot be guaranteed.

---

<sup>1 - There isn't anything in the Java SE that directly *implements* the uniqueness guarantee.  However, the thread id sequence number is a 64 bit value, so if a JVM created a new thread every millisecond, it would take ~580 million years for the sequence to return to 0.  This is not a *practical* concern.</sup>